# Swift, Firebase retrieving data from unknown child

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I would like to retrieve data from Firebase database *child*. But I don’t know the child node name.

My database looks like this:

- Users

  - UserID

    - 2017 (I don't know this string. It's 2017, 2018... or something else?)

      - November (I don't know this string. It's November, January... or something else?)

        - Key: Value (I need this data)
        - Key: Value (I need this data)
        - Key: Value (I need this data)

I tried this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let userID = Firebase.Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid

    databaseRef = Database.database().reference().child("Users").child(userID!)
    databaseRef.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

        var newItems = [Post]()

        for item in snapshot.children {
            let newPost = Post(snapshot: item as! DataSnapshot)
            newItems.append(newPost)
        }

        self.postArray = newItems
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        print(newItems)

    }) { (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

Comment: So what are you trying to do here exactly, figure out the child node name? It seems like your code is fine otherwise..

Comment: Yes, i want to figure out the name (String) of the Child’s . I don’t now if the child name (String) is November or October or something else. I know only .child(„Users“).child(UseriD) but the other child’s (String) are unknown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your current code you loop over the years already. If you also want to loop over the months, you'll need to add an extra `for`:

```
databaseRef = Database.database().reference().child("Users").child(userID!)
databaseRef.observe(.value, with: {(snapshot) in

    for year in snapshot.children.allObjects as [DataSnapshot] {
        for month in year.children.allObjects as [DataSnapshot] {
            print(month.key)
        }
    }


}){
    (error) in
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

This will print the months. You can get properties of the specific month with:

```
print(month.childSnapshot(forPath:"Key").value)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. 

for year in snapshot.children.allObjects as [DataSnapshot] {
        for month in year.children.allObjects as [DataSnapshot] {
            print(month.key)
        }

thats how it works. just a little something changed